# Customizing notifications on Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

So far I have been setting manually a notification for all my events in Google Chrome for the previous day at 9PM. I have to manually find out how many hours that is, which is a pain.

Is there a way to customize the notifications for a specific date, instead of a number of minutes or hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, there is no way to natively customize the notification in calendar without using Apps Script. Sending the Daily Agenda might be the closest to what you want.

In the calendar with the events, click on the drop down arrow and select "Edit notifications (or, go to that calendar's settings and click on the Edit notifications tab at the top).

Scroll down to Daily agenda and make sure the email box is ticked. This sends an email at 5AM local with all of your events for the day.